# missing ) after argument list when inserting xml into paragraph

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to show a block of xml in a dialog window with this code:

```
function ShowFaultMessage(message) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: "#btnShowFault" },
        buttons: [{
            text: "Copy",
            id: "btnCopy",
            Click: function () { return true; }
        }]
    });

    document.getElementById("faultParagraph").innerText = message;

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");

    $("#btnCopy").zclip({
        path: '../Scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: document.getElementById("faultParagraph").innerText,
        afterCopy: function () { }
    });
};
```

The "message" variable contains the xml. This works if "message" is just a standard string, but blows up with "missing ) after argument list" if it's a string of xml. Is there a way to make this work? I assume it must have a problem with non escaped characters in the xml.

This is my dialog html:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Fault Message">
<p id="faultParagraph" class="paragraph-message"></p>
```

and the XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" s:mustUnderstand="1">http://services.com/SendValidationFaultFault</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ValidationFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/practices/EnterpriseLibrary/2007/01/wcf/validation">
                    <Details xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF">
                        <d6p1:ValidationDetail>
                            <d6p1:Key>Cost</d6p1:Key>
                            <d6p1:Message>Cost must be greater than .01.</d6p1:Message>
                            <d6p1:Tag>invoice</d6p1:Tag>
                        </d6p1:ValidationDetail>
                        <d6p1:ValidationDetail>
                            <d6p1:Key>Cost</d6p1:Key>
                            <d6p1:Message>Cost must be greater than .01.</d6p1:Message>
                            <d6p1:Tag>invoice</d6p1:Tag>
                        </d6p1:ValidationDetail>
                    </Details>
                </ValidationFault>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: `... but blows up if it's a string of xml.` Could you show us an example of XML that it blows up with and the actual error message or symptoms?

Comment: The error message is in the thread title. The symptom is that it does nothing and displays that error message in the console tab in the browser debugger. Added sample xml that blows it up.

Comment: The error you described is a JavaScript error, and that doesn't sound like something that would be caused by the value of some random string. Exactly how does the XML become involved here? How is the "ShowFaultMessage()" actually invoked?

Comment: I have a button that when clicked invokes that function and passes in the xml as a string in as the message variable. If the message variable is something like "This is a test string" the ShowFaultMessage function works just fine. Pops up the dialog and shows that text. If the message is xml string like the one in the post, it blows up with that error message. So it has to be something in that function. I can only assume it is having escaping issues.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle reproducing your problem?

Comment: I can try. Never used it. New to MVC dev.

Comment: btw, is just when the `message`is a xml (not "plain text") that is causing the error or is a case of "when every thing is set up for me to test with some xml the page fails to load (or something)"?

Comment: It's only when the message is string of xml. If it's a regular old string of plain text, it all works fine.

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementById("faultParagraph").innerText = escape(message);`? (that should turn your xml into somekind of "plain text", if you want to keep the `escape`remember to call `unescape` when setting the copy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83446/discussion-between-prusse-and-g-t-w-d).

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to use Json.Encode for my parameter into the function. I made the change where I build my button that calls the function. I now have this:

```
 return new HtmlString(string.Format("<input type='submit' id='btnShowFault' onclick='ShowFaultMessage({0})' value='Fault' />", Json.Encode(item.Fault.Message)));
```

Thanks to Prusse for helping me with this.